# Operation 10**(-9) correct in python, but wrong in Cython

Tags: python, cython

Very basic question:
in my `python 2.7` code I have situation roughly as follows:

```
b=5.0*10**(-9)
a=9
print(a)
c=a/(1.0*b)
```

the code runs in `python` / `spyder` (64bit), but fails in `Cython`, because of a float division by 0. The printed number is 0. When I define

```
b=0.000000005
```

the division is fine and the printed number, too. What is the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce your error with `cython 0.22` and I think this error is related to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/goVpote2ScY) at `cython-users`.

It seems that `cython` gets into trouble when calculating `10**-9`. If you use `10**-9.0` instead, everything works fine.

Note, that you could get rid of the error and prettify the code snippet by replacing `5.0*10**(-9)` by `5e-9`.

Nevertheless this seems to be a bug in `cython` and not in your code base.